# looking for Microsoft SQL Server wrapper library to federate

Tags: db2, wrapper, federation

I'm serious in trouble. IBM's response is slow.

I'm looking for module that db2 federate to SQLserver.
I guess this module is called Microsoft SQL Server wrapper library.

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS2K5T_10.5.0/com.ibm.swg.im.iis.found.conn.fw.mss.doc/topics/rlsmss13.html

Please tell us where i get this module.
we looking for this module in IBM's support site and media and %DB2_INSTALLD_PATH%.

Comment: The  wrapper for SQL-Server is part of the "Infosphere Federation Server" (also known as Infosphere Information Server)  product at *current versions*.   It is no longer a part of the basic Db2 LUW product.

Comment: In addition, if you have the AESE edition of V10.5 Db2 LUW then you also get the wrappers for other data sources like Oracle or SQL-Server etc.  To find your edition name, use db2licm -l (on Db2 LUW).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank  you for your information.
I could wrapper module from fixpack,but I don't have license  of  Infosphere Federation Server.because de2s edition I have is workgroup edition!
 So I plan for  sqlserver to link server.